# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm retrieving name of user from firebase in appBar when user is logged in. I retrieved it successfully.But when user is not logged in. I'm getting error that 'uid' is null. I believe the
error is in my initUser(). But i cant seem to fix it !

E/flutter (16741): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null.
E/flutter (16741): Receiver: null
E/flutter (16741): Tried calling: uid

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isAdmin;

  const MainScreen({Key key, this.isAdmin}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState(this.isAdmin);
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  bool isPressed = false;
  bool userLoggedIn =false;
  //var _userName;
//  Future<FirebaseUser> getUser() {
//    return _auth.currentUser();
//  }
  Future<String> currentUser() async {
   user = await _auth.currentUser();
    return user != null ? user.uid : null;
  }
  FirebaseUser user;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    initUser();

  }
  String userid;

  initUser() async {
    user = await _auth.currentUser();
    userid = user.uid;
    setState(() {});
  }

  bool isAdmin = true;
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  //final authData = snapshot.data;
  _MainScreenState(this.isAdmin);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
    CurrentUser _currentUser = Provider.of<CurrentUser>(context, listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
      //backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Colors.cyan, Colors.yellow], stops: [0.5, 1.0],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        //title: Text('Property Host'),

        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          Expanded(

            child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                //Image.asset('assets/index.jpg', fit: BoxFit.cover,height:16,width:16),
                Container(
                    margin: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 50),
                    child: Text('Property Host',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 19),)),

              user!=null ? StreamBuilder(stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').where("uid", isEqualTo: userid).snapshots(),

    // ignore: missing_return
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.data == null)
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      //final userDocument = snapshot.data;
      //final title=  snapshot.data.userocument['displayName']);
      //CircularProgressIndicator();
      return Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            // ignore: missing_return
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              print(user.uid);
              return user != null
                  ? Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 17, left: 40),
                child: Text(
                    snapshot.data.documents.elementAt(index)['displayName']),
              )
                  : IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                // ignore: missing_return
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/LoginScreen');
                },
              );
            }
        ),
      );
    }
```

Comment: The answer is in your question: "But when user is not logged in. I'm getting error that 'uid' is null."

Answer (score 0):

When the user is not logged in, the `await _auth.currentUser()` will return `null`. Which means calling `uid` on `user` (which is null) will result in an error.

You can wrap it around a null check in an if statement.

```dart
initUser() async {
  user = await _auth.currentUser();
  if (user != null) {
    userid = user.uid;
  } else {
    // User is not available. Do something else
  }
  setState(() {});
}
```